# Image processing for improved color detection (python)

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, color-detection

I use deep learning algorithms to detect elements in an image.
Once these elements are detected I try to recover two colours in this image.

Here is an example of the images I process:

[Non-contrasted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H7wO.png)

To make it easier I contrast the image to improve the colours here is an example:

[Contrasted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHaqr.png)

My goal is to find in this image the blue and red colour, it is at this precise moment that I block.
When the image is of good quality I manage to find the colours but on other images of less good quality it is very difficult to get good results.

Knowing that the colours that I would like to find are the following:
red, green, blue, yellow, grey, brown, violet, turquoise, orange, pink

Do you know of any image processing methods or machine learning models that could solve my problem?

**More images for exemple :**

[Good image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhGVY.jpg)

[Good image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cdHy.png)

[Bad image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3efwa.jpg)

[Bad image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRAp9.jpg)

**And the code i used :**

```
import cv2 
import copy

from sklearn import multioutput


from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from skimage.color import rgb2lab, deltaE_cie76
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance


class ImageColorDetection(object):
    
    origineFrame : list = []
    imageFrame : list = []
    hsvFrame : list = []
    
    colorList : dict = {}
    
    def __init__(self, array=None, path=None, rotated=0):
        self.colorList = {}
        
        if path is not None:
            self.origineFrame = Image.open(path).convert('RGB').rotate(rotated)
            im_output = Image.open(path).convert('RGB').rotate(rotated)
        elif array is not None:
            self.origineFrame = Image.fromarray(array).convert('RGB').rotate(rotated)
            im_output = Image.fromarray(array).convert('RGB').rotate(rotated)
        else:
            raise Exception('Aucune image n\'est renseigner dans le constructeur')

        
        #im_output = im_output.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
        #im_output = im_output.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE)
        #im_output = ImageOps.autocontrast(im_output, cutoff = 5, ignore = 5)

        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Color(im_output)
        im_output = enhancer.enhance(3)

        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im_output)
        im_output = enhancer.enhance(0.9)

        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(im_output)
        im_output = enhancer.enhance(2)

        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(im_output)
        im_output = enhancer.enhance(1.6)

        
        im_output = np.array(im_output)

        self.imageFrame = cv2.cvtColor(im_output, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        self.hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(self.imageFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        
    def findColor(self, color_rgb, color_title, color_upper, color_lower):
        
        kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8") 
        
        color_mask = cv2.inRange(self.hsvFrame, color_lower, color_upper) 
        color_mask = cv2.dilate(color_mask, kernal) 
        res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(self.imageFrame, self.imageFrame, 
                                mask = color_mask)

        current_area = 0
        x, y, w, h, (r,g,b) = 0, 0, 0, 0, color_rgb
        # Creating contour to track blue color 
        im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(color_mask, 
                                        cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

        for pic, contour in enumerate(contours): 
            area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if(area > 1000 and current_area < area):
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                self.colorList[color_title] = x, y, w, h, color_rgb
                current_area = area
            
        return color_title in self.colorList.keys()
    
    def ShowImage(self):
        tmp_img = np.asarray(copy.copy(self.origineFrame))
        
        for color in self.colorList:
                
            cv2.rectangle(
                tmp_img, 
                (self.colorList[color][0], self.colorList[color][1]), 
                ((self.colorList[color][0] + self.colorList[color][2]), (self.colorList[color][1] + self.colorList[color][3])), 
                self.colorList[color][4], 2)
            
            cv2.putText(
                tmp_img,
                color, 
                (self.colorList[color][0], self.colorList[color][1]), 
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                1.0, 
                self.colorList[color][4])
        #plt.imshow(tmp_img, multioutput=True)
        return tmp_img
        
    def ShowImageContrast(self):
        tmp_img = copy.copy(self.imageFrame)
        tmp_img = cv2.cvtColor(tmp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        for color in self.colorList:
                
            cv2.rectangle(
                tmp_img, 
                (self.colorList[color][0], self.colorList[color][1]), 
                ((self.colorList[color][0] + self.colorList[color][2]), (self.colorList[color][1] + self.colorList[color][3])), 
                self.colorList[color][4], 3)
            
            cv2.putText(
                tmp_img,
                color, 
                (self.colorList[color][0], self.colorList[color][1]), 
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                0.8, 
                self.colorList[color][4])
          
        #plt.imshow(tmp_img, multioutput=True)
        return tmp_img
    
    def RGB2HEX(self, color):
        return "#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(int(color[0]), int(color[1]), int(color[2]))

    def get_colors(self, contrasted, number_of_colors, show_chart):
        
        if contrasted:
            modified_image = cv2.resize(np.asarray(self.imageFrame), (600, 400), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        else:
            modified_image = cv2.resize(np.asarray(self.origineFrame), (600, 400), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        #modified_image = cv2.resize(np.asarray(self.origineFrame), (600, 400), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        modified_image = modified_image.reshape(modified_image.shape[0]*modified_image.shape[1], 3)
        
        clf = KMeans(n_clusters = number_of_colors)
        labels = clf.fit_predict(modified_image)
        
        counts = Counter(labels)
        # sort to ensure correct color percentage
        counts = dict(sorted(counts.items()))
        
        center_colors = clf.cluster_centers_
        # We get ordered colors by iterating through the keys
        ordered_colors = [center_colors[i] for i in counts.keys()]
        hex_colors = [self.RGB2HEX(ordered_colors[i]) for i in counts.keys()]
        rgb_colors = [ordered_colors[i] for i in counts.keys()]
        
        print("Nombre de couleur : ", len(hex_colors))
        if (show_chart):
            plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6))
            plt.pie(counts.values(), labels = hex_colors, colors = hex_colors)
        
        return counts, hex_colors, rgb_colors
```

**Attempt with HSV :**

With the HSV my problem persists I found a tutorial that sets up the problem I'm trying to solve but it doesn't work on the images I'm trying to process, do you have any knowledge on the subject (courses, youtube videos, articles)?

Voici l'article en question : https://towardsdatascience.com/color-identification-in-images-machine-learning-application-b26e770c4c71

Comment: How are you doing it ?
You should take a look at HSV color extraction.
You can also try to go through each pixel of the image by hand, and retrieve it if it is in the range that you want to keep

Comment: Il use RGB color for extract color in image, show code in post

Comment: "white balance". your pictures have tints. -- https://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 2):

Maybe OpenCV's inRange() might help?

```
import cv2

hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_hsvcolorspace = np.array([hue_min, saturation_min, value_min])
upper_hsvcolorspace = np.array([hue_max, saturation_max, value_max])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_hsvcolorspace, upper_hsvcolorspace)
```

You can look up your expected HSV values [here for example](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html). Just be aware that the ranges in OpenCV are different: 0-179 (hue) and 0-255 (saturation, value).

Can you post more images: good ones, bad ones and the expected output?

Comment: I add more image in post.
I use RGB range in my project,, is HSV different ? why ?

Comment: HSV is different, yes, but you can easily convert back and forth between RGB and HSV. I propose HSV because cv2.inRange expects an HSV image and because HSV is more intuitive and closer to how us humans would describe colours. Play with the tool at the link I gave you and you will understand.

Comment: HSV is better for color detection, easier to tune ranges for more than few images. Read [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/why-do-we-use-the-hsv-colour-space-so-often-in-vision-and-image-processing). Also I think that you should try sharpening the images more.

Answer (score 1):

Convert you image to HSV `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`, than create threshold vectors like

```
lower_green = np.array([30, 0, 0])
upper_green = np.array([90, 255, 255])
```

Using this thresholds you can filter different colors, read more about HSV

```
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_green, upper_green)
```

Comment: I use RGB color, i add code in post